# How can em be better than px in Zurb foundations responsive grid?

Tags: css, media-queries, zurb-foundation, breakpoints

The Zurb Foundation Media Queries are defined in em:

```
$small-range: (0em, 40em); /* 0, 640px */
$medium-range: (40.063em, 64em); /* 641px, 1024px */
$large-range: (64.063em, 90em); /* 1025px, 1440px */
$xlarge-range: (90.063em, 120em); /* 1441px, 1920px */
$xxlarge-range: (120.063em); /* 1921px */
```

I don't understand how this can be a good idea.
I have to assume I'm missing something here and I'm eager to learn what!

If I wanted to change the body font size, I'd have to recalculate all of these, right?
[I'd use PXtoEM.com](http://pxtoem.com/)

Been looking through the internet for a good answer to this but I haven't found one...

**So I still don't get it, why use em instead of px in this case?**
(My experience with css is: if I don't get it, it's something I have to learn)

Comment: _“why use em instead of px in this case?”_ – to make the layout react to the available space in relation to the currently used font-size of course …

Comment: So... "If I wanted to change the body font size, I'd have to recalculate all of these, right?" :)

Comment: You build your size with sensible font-sizes given in `em` – and then the _user_ changes the base font size in their browser if they think that is too small/big for them to read comfortably …

Answer (score 0):

I've recently been introduced to ems using Zurb's front-end framework [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/).

From my understanding, ems and percents result in elements displaying more accurate proportions with respect to other, screen display sizes, etc.

There are several conversion chats and calculators available to convert pixels to ems.

Here's a good reference:
Nice input/output fields:
http://all-markup-news.com/px-to-em/